# Почему то воспринимает ctx как отдельный аргумент

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Есть функция, которая работала но спустя неделю почему-то нет и вроде я ниче не менял. Суть в чем. Пользователь пишет +user Name Surname Year и создается под него роли, ему меняется ник на сервере и тд. Почему-то когда я указываю 3 аргумента (Name Surname Year) пишет Missing Permissions.
Это из-за ctx, так как я его использую в теле функции. Если я его не использую, то все работает, но в теле есть 2 задачи, которым нужны ctx - изменение ника автору команды и выдача ролей ему.
Почему функция воспринимает ctx как обязательный аргумент, а раньше нет и как это исправить?

```py
@bot.command()
async def user(ctx, name, surname, year):
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите в вопрос конкретную ошибку, которая у вас возникает

Comment: `ctx` — обязательный аргумент для команды бота. Просто из-за того, что он есть, ошибка `MissingPermissions` точно появляться не будет. Возможно у бота недостаточно прав для создания роли или еще на что-нибудь? Добавьте текст ошибки в текст вопроса.

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions